# react native run android don't work, and can't install the app

Tags: react-native

When i run "react-native run-android", the terminal show:

C:\Users\PC\Documents\React Native\projeo>react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 864 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
>   11 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 8 up-to-date
>   <-------------> 0% WAITING
>   IDLE
>   IDLE
>   IDLE

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > 8 exceptions were raised by workers:
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > 8 exceptions were raised by workers:
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:610:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:628:15)
at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\PC\Documents\React Native\projeo\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
at buildAndRun (C:\Users\PC\Documents\React Native\projeo\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
at C:\Users\PC\Documents\React Native\projeo\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\PC\Documents\React Native\projeo\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:164:9)
```

What is happend?

Comment: I use Windows 8.1

Comment: Do you have your emulator running?

Comment: Yes! Genymotion Sansung Galaxy S8.

Answer (score 1):

I solve it, installing netframework 3.5 and 4.6.

Comment: You should accept this as the answer. I think you get a badge for that ;)